# Symfony 4.2 utf8 data cut off when saving to MySQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-4.2

I'm saving a heading from a CSV file to the database.

Viewed with less on Ubuntu the file starts like this:

```
    Date,Supermarket,Speciality,Takeaway,Caf<E9>/restaurant
    1/06/2019,0.039175903,-0.01496395,0.03603785,0.029072835
    1/07/2019,0.039399919,-0.008250166,0.022385733,0.015478668
```

The heading data is ($csvHeader)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Date
    [1] => Supermarket
    [2] => Speciality
    [3] => Takeaway
    [4] => Caf�/restaurant
)
```

`ord(substr($csvHeader,3,1)) === 233`

This is read with the following function

```
protected function getCsvHeaders()
{
    $fh = fopen( $this->getCsvPath(), 'r+' );
    $firstrow = fgetcsv( $fh );
    fclose( $fh );
    return $firstrow;
}
```

This is saved to a table DataConfiguration:

```
$dataConf
  ->setColumns(serialize($csvHeader));
```

which is set to utf8mb4:

```
    show create table data_configuration;
    +--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Table              | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
    +--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | data_configuration | CREATE TABLE `data_configuration` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `data_set_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `file_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `columns` varchar(7500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `unique_idx` (`data_set_id`,`file_type_id`),
    KEY `IDX_54A0B1FD70053C01` (`data_set_id`),
    KEY `IDX_54A0B1FD9E2A35A8` (`file_type_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_54A0B1FD70053C01` FOREIGN KEY (`data_set_id`) REFERENCES `data_set` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_54A0B1FD9E2A35A8` FOREIGN KEY (`file_type_id`) REFERENCES `file_type` (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13176 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

Doctrine seems to be configured for utf8mb4 as well:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
#        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        options:
            1001: true
```

However the data gets cut off at the utf8 character and subsequent unserialize fails. I can reproduce this on my Ubuntu 18/ AWS RDS environment as well as my local MacOS/Brew environment.

What other avenues can I explore to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add the raw contents of the .CSV file?

Comment: @OMiShah Have pasted first 3 lines viewed with less, is that sufficient?

Comment: so that character is the ``Latin small e with acute ( é )``

Comment: The «é» char corresponds to the ASCII code 130, not 233 which is «Ú». Can you try ord(mb_substr($csvHeader,3,1)) and post the code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @MarcosLabad . The result is 233 as well. I have added the code that reads the first line as well.

Comment: @MarcosLabad ASCII has only 128 codes and no accentuated characters. In some supersets like Windows-1252, `é` has the code 233. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing a text file with `fgetcsv()`. Its documentation states you can encounter issues when using single-byte encoded files:

> The locale settings are taken into account by this function. If LC_CTYPE is e.g. en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte encodings may be read wrongly by this function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

If your file contains French characters that exist beyond the basic ASCII table, you may set this variable to another value:

1. List installed locales : `sh locale -a`

> en_US.utf8
>
> fr_FR.iso885915
>
> ...

The output may vary. I cannot tell you a locale that's guaranteed to exist on your machine. You have to pick something like ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252, not UTF-8.

2. Before calling `fgetcsv()`, set the locale to something that matches the file encoding:

```php
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'fr_FR.iso885915');
```

3. Call `fgetcsv()`

Alternatively, you can manually convert the encoding:

```php
$row_utf8 = mb_convert_encoding($row_raw, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");
```

What does `file your.csv` gives?

Comment: file your.csv shows: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators, but mb_convert_encoding($row_raw, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8") converts the accented e into ? Its sort of just as good as removing the character completely with a regex.

Comment: What I'm looking for is actually solely for the text not to be cut off when saved to the database. I'm not clear why this happens, independent of catching the right character from the file.

Comment: @jdog There's a bunch of flags to make PHP more verbose. I would think it would log something upon truncating your data.

Comment: Yes, no difference either. Lots of locales on my mac, but do not convert any other way either

Comment: @jdog Could you give examples of locales you tried passing to `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, $x)`? Does the data look truncated when you print it? Does `getCsvHeaders()` keep getting the �? Have you made sure all the scripts are encoded in non-extended ASCII or UTF8?

Comment: I have tried for example "en_GB.ISO8859-1". Yes I still see the �. I'm unclear what scripts you are referring to?

Comment: The .php scripts